# Dropdown menu boostrap highlight color change

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I cant change a highligted/hovered li's background color.
I've got following code:
P.S : i have custom font settings, but this doesn't affect anything.. i guess.
HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id='settings-content'>
            <li><a href="#"><font>Account Settings</font> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user pull-right"></span></a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><font>User Stats</font> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats pull-right"></span></a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><font>Messages</font> <span class="badge pull-right"> 1 </span></a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><font>Groups</font> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right"></span></a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="../Cursed Gods/Auth/exit.php"><font>Sign Out</font> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out pull-right"></span></a></li>
          </ul> 

          <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle="dropdown" class='dropdown'><div id='settings'></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#424242;
    font-size:20px;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
}
ul.dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 10px solid #424242;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 16px;
    z-index: 10;
}
ul.dropdown-menu:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 12px solid #424242;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    right: 14px;
    z-index: 9;
}

#menu-games{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:150px;
}
#menu-games:before{
right: 120px;
}
#menu-games:after{
right: 118px;
}

 .dropdown-menu > li> a:hover, .dropdown-menu > a:focus {
            background-image:none ;
 }
 .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
            background-color:red;
 }
```

PLZ help!!!All of solutions i saw on "stack" didn't work((( idk what's the problem.

Comment: link u css after bootstrap.css?

Comment: LOL man thnx , such a stupid mistake.